# Subimport star breaks listings languages

Tags: listings, import

`\subimport*{}{}` from the package import  seems to break listings languages, but only if `listings` with a language hasn't been used in the root document:

```
! Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested language.
```

My hypothesis is that the starred version of `subimport` is breaking the path for listings, but somehow it's cached if the listing is used outside the import first.

Is there a solution to this (outside of not using the starred sub import; I'd like to keep using it if possible...)

MWE below.

---

A/List.tex:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

% Uncommenting the problem, oddly enough.
%\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
%public static void main(String[] args) {} 
%\end{lstlisting}
\subimport*{Nest/Nest/}{nested}

\end{document}
```

A/Nest/Nest/nested.tex:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
//Returns true
private static bool P() { 
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: It's best to describe the problem as much as possible in your question. Can you specify what you mean by "break"? Do you get an error?

Comment: @Jubobs Whoops. Editing to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the package documentation:

> To avoid searching the `TEXINPUTS` path when importing files, use the ‘star’ versions of the commands: `\import*` and `\subimport*`.

This means that `pdflatex` is not able to look for files other than those in the specified directory. However, settings for `listings` languages are imported at usage time, so the memory is not cluttered with tens of useless languages.

Solution: use `\lstloadlanguages`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstloadlanguages{Java}

\begin{document}

\subimport*{mattnest/mattnest/}{nested}

\end{document}
```

[image]